# How to close Console Application window automatically

Tags: c#, console, console-application

I am running a Console Application and when the last line of text is written to the Console Window I would like the Console Window to automatically close after 5 seconds.
Now there is always the message of '**Press any key to continue**'. Is there a way to suppress this message and close the window after 5 seconds?

I have tried `return 0;`, `System.Environment.Exit(1)`, but with no success.
Any help is very much appreciated.

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("This is the last message.");
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    // System.Environment.Exit(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is the "Press any key to continue" message coming from, the code you have posted should be a console application that runs for 5 seconds and then closes.

Comment: Yes to have "Press any key to continue" showing up you have to actualy do make it appear

Comment: Are you running it on debug?

Comment: John357, if you want to appreciate someone at this site for help, you can upvote his post and accept it as an answer (click on the check mark beside). Please read this short help article [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

`Press any key to continue` is by default provided by Microsoft in development IDE. Whenever you run an application from IDE, you must be expecting any output right? This is given for that purpose so that user can see the output generated. No matter your project mode is `Debug` or `Release` you'll get this message. If you'll see in all the MSDN documentation (suppose [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx)), they specifically mention in code sample:-

```
// Keep the console open in debug mode.
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Because when you run the application directly using `Ctrl+F5` you get this message "Press any key to continue" but you'll not get this message while debugging.

If you will run this from outside the `IDE` i.e. directly by double clicking the `.exe` file generated, you'll not find this message, also in real-time you will run this file from a BAT file or something (Obviously you will not ask the end user to run your app from Visual Studio IDE right) then too you won't get this message.

Simply use your code (mentioned below) and run the `.exe` file present in `bin` directory, You'll get your desired result.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter something");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

So, In short this is only specific to **IDE**.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling the application and running it should close the console automatically (with Windows command prompt). That is unless you open a command prompt and run the program from within it.

You can't force the console to close itself, your program just runs inside it.